# Interpreting Typekit Network Requests

Tags: performance, http, google-chrome-devtools, typekit

Can someone explain the bottom four network requests shown below for Typekit?

What I don't understand is:

- Why do they show `0 B` for size but `17.2 KB` (et al) for content?
- Are there really four HTTP requests occurring for these font files?

The same data is reported regardless of whether compression is enabled.

Dev Tools says the calls are being initiated by Modernizr in the line below that reads `bool = node.offsetTop === 9;`

```
tests['touch'] = function() {
  var bool;

  if (('ontouchstart' in window) || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch) {
    bool = true;
  } else {
    injectElementWithStyles(['@media (', prefixes.join('touch-enabled),('), mod, ')', '{#modernizr{top:9px;position:absolute}}'].join(''), function(node) {
      bool = node.offsetTop === 9;
    });
  }

  return bool;
};
```

[image: Chrom Dev Tools: Network Requests for Typekit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are `base64`ed - that means that the files were converted to a [text embeddable data format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), and then inlined in the file. 0Bs were used for downloading the request, since it was embedded in another file, but the content of that data URI was 17.2KB

Comment: Thanks for responding. Am I correct in thinking that no HTTP requests were made for these line items?

Comment: Correct - no request was made because it was included inside another file. You can actually [filter out data uris](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/12/DevTools-Digest-December-2013) since its not terribly useful to being with

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that's what was confusing me -- seeing items in the Network tab that don't involve network requests. Filtering those out seems like the right option to me.